# How to remove this Jason response(timestamp, status, error, path)? I just want to get object data

Tags: java, elixir-jason

{
"courseId": 23,
"courseName": "science",
"courseCode": "SC100",
"courseDescription": "linear algebra",
"courseDuration": "6 m",
"createdDate": 1630438611000,
"updatedDate": null,
"removeImages": []
}**{
"timestamp": 1630614081354,
"status": 200,
"error": "OK",
"path": "/api/editcourse/23"
}**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use [Jackson Project](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) for that task.

**Alternative 1**

Since you have 2 values in the same Json and you want only the first, you can use `readTree(String)` method from `ObjectMapper` class. It will skip the second value.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

JsonNode jsonNode = mapper.readTree(jsonResponse);

System.out.println(jsonNode.toPrettyString());
```

Output:

```
{
  "courseId" : 23,
  "courseName" : "science",
  "courseCode" : "SC100",
  "courseDescription" : "linear algebra",
  "courseDuration" : "6 m",
  "createdDate" : 1630438611000,
  "updatedDate" : null,
  "removeImages" : [ ]
}
```

**Alternative 2**

Using method `readValues(JsonParser, Class<T>)` you can read all values an iterate selecting only the ones you need.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

Iterator<?> iterator = mapper.readValues(new JsonFactory().createParser(jsonResponse), Map.class);

Object object = iterator.next();

System.out.println(object);
```

Output:

```
{courseId=23, courseName=science, courseCode=SC100, courseDescription=linear algebra, courseDuration=6 m, createdDate=1630438611000, updatedDate=null, removeImages=[]}
```